# Oracle listagg query

Tags: oracle11g, pivot, listagg

This is my query result:

`WEEKENDDATE CCNAME              PHNAME           RATIO
08-Feb-15   Apple Line 1 - Day  L&I Work         0.45
08-Feb-15   Apple Line 1 - Day  Sorter           6.85
08-Feb-15   Apple Line 1 - Day  Tray Fill       12.93
08-Feb-15   Apple Line 1 - Day  WH General Labor 5.6
08-Feb-15   Apple Line 1 - Day  WH Supervisor    1.48
15-Feb-15   Apple Line 1 - Day  L&I Work         0.42
15-Feb-15   Apple Line 1 - Day  Sorter           6.09
15-Feb-15   Apple Line 1 - Day  Tray Fill       11.9
15-Feb-15   Apple Line 1 - Day  WH General Labor 5.42
15-Feb-15   Apple Line 1 - Day  WH Supervisor    3.46
22-Feb-15   Apple Line 1 - Day  L&I Work         0.43
22-Feb-15   Apple Line 1 - Day  Sorter           6.01
22-Feb-15   Apple Line 1 - Day  Tray Fill       12.09
22-Feb-15   Apple Line 1 - Day  WH General Labor 4.9
22-Feb-15   Apple Line 1 - Day  WH Supervisor    1.71`

My boss wants the data sideways.
**Is there a way to get my query result formatted like this:**

`CCNAME              PHNAME          08-Feb-15 15-Feb-15 22-Feb-15
Apple Line 1 - Day  L&I Work             0.45      0.42      0.43
Apple Line 1 - Day  Sorter               6.85      6.09      6.01
Apple Line 1 - Day  Tray Fill           12.93     11.9      12.09
Apple Line 1 - Day  WH General Labor     5.6       5.42      4.9
Apple Line 1 - Day  WH Supervisor        1.48      3.46      1.71`

**or like this:**

`CCNAME              PHNAME             08-FEB-15,15-FEB-15,22-FEB-15
Apple Line 1 - Day  L&I Work                             .45,.42,.43
Apple Line 1 - Day  Sorter                            6.85,6.09,6.01
Apple Line 1 - Day  Tray Fill                       12.93,11.9,12.09
Apple Line 1 - Day  WH General Labor                    5.6,5.42,4.9
Apple Line 1 - Day  WH Supervisor                     1.48,3.46,1.71`

Here is the query I was able to figure out:
Please note that **I do not know the date range in advance.**
That depends on how many week(s) the user asks for.

```
select ccname, phname, listagg(weekenddate||','||ratio,'; ') 
within group(order by ccname, phname) ratio
from
(...leaving out this code...)
group by ccname, phname
```

But the result below is not quite good enough: Can I use 'listagg' or should I be researching 'pivot' instead?

`CCNAME              PHNAME              RATIO
Apple Line 1 - Day  L&I Work            08-FEB-15,.45;15-FEB-15,.42;22-FEB-15,.43
Apple Line 1 - Day  Sorter              08-FEB-15,6.85;15-FEB-15,6.09;22-FEB-15,6.01
Apple Line 1 - Day  Tray Fill           08-FEB-15,12.93;15-FEB-15,11.9;22-FEB-15,12.09
Apple Line 1 - Day  WH General Labor    08-FEB-15,5.6;15-FEB-15,5.42;22-FEB-15,4.9
Apple Line 1 - Day  WH Supervisor       08-FEB-15,1.48;15-FEB-15,3.46;22-FEB-15,1.71`

Comment: If you don't know, how many columns you will have, the only way you can use is `LISTAGG`.

Comment: OIC thanks. Most likely I will be bringing my Oracle queries over to SQL Server (using OPENQUERY) where I can create temporary tables and not have to format in Oracle after all. However, I will still have to figure it out in SQL Server :-)

Comment: As it turns out, I am going to create a Visual Studio Crosstab Crystal Report to accomplish what I want to do.

Comment: For T SQL / SQL Server this helped me:    http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1434207-391-1.aspx

Comment: For PLSQL I am using LISTAGG, I think your issue is related to formating the RATIO